# AWS CDK - how to get the arn of the assumed user directly

Tags: typescript, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-sts

How do I get the arn of the assumed user who is going to deploy the CDK stack in CDK?
The format that's in arn:aws:sts::accountID:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/user@email.com

e.g. the arn that appears when i run `aws sts get-caller-identity`

I tried to retrieve from the cdk library `iam.Role.???` construct but none seems to have related to assumed role

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: need to provision to grant permissions to whoever that assumed the role and deploy the stack. The provisioning template is meant to let people to deploy in their own account

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that's a feature supported by the CDK itself. However, you can import the AWS SDK and retrieve the value from the SDK and use it in your code.

Comment: thanks for responding. unfortunately i am looking from cdk perspective to automate the resource provisioning.